# "Table is marked as crashed" - fixed by CHECK TABLE ...?

Tags: mysql, myisam

I did "CHECK TABLE mytable" and there were two rows with Msg_text:
"Table is marked as crashed"
"OK"

I took about 10 mins to review how 'myisamchk' works, then ran CHECK TABLE again to verify the error, but to my surprise the error was no longer there.

I reviewed CHECK TABLE documentation and see sentence ..

"For MyISAM tables, the key statistics are updated as well."

The table is "MyISAM".

Is it possible that ...
- the NON-updated stats were causing the "...crashed" error
- and that updating those stats via CHECK TABLE resolved the error?

Thanks

Comment: forgot to mention - i'm not using "--myisam-recover" in my.cnf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works something like this...

While mysqld is running, it has a flag set in any index (.MYI file) that it is using.  Normally index updates are written to the .MYI file, but with no sense of urgency, since they are cached in the "key_buffer".

When mysqld terminates un-gracefully (eg, because of a power failure), mysqld has no chance to clear the flag.  After restarting, mysqld sees the flag and says "oh, panic; this index may be corrupted".  Then, you have to come in and take action to clear the flag and, if necessary, fix the corruption using `REPAIR TABLE` or the equivalent myisamchk with suitable arguments.

Often, the index is not really corrupt, and the CHECK/REPAIR is not really needed.  But MySQL can't be sure.  Hence, the somewhat alarming message.

It is possible to have a setting so that MyISAM tables will be checked and repaired during startup.  I rarely see [`myisam_recover_options`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_myisam-recover-options) set to anything other than `OFF`.

If you switch to InnoDB, you can mostly forget about all this stuff.